# Web Api routing issue when using uri parameter and query string

Tags: c#, url-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm struggling to get some Web Api 2.2 routing working correctly.  I have a route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "OrgAdminGetOrgUsers",
            routeTemplate: "organisations/{id}/users",
            defaults: new { controller = "OrganisationDetails", action = "GetUsersInAnOrganisation" }                
        );
```

The problem I'm having is that when I add a query string for making the GET searchable, my routing stops working and I get 404's.  I've looked everywhere for examples of using both Uri parameters and a query string, but I can't find anything.  It seems like something people would do a lot though?  When I remove the query string and the optional parameters from the controller the routing works fine.

Uri:

```
organisations/3/users?orderby=asc&orderByColumn=surname&start=1&end=15
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersInAnOrganisation(int id, string email = "", string firstName = "", string surname = "", string orderByColumn = "", string orderBy = "asc", int start = -1, int end = -1)
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've managed to get it working, the controller needed to be declared with [FromUri] for the id parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersInAnOrganisation([FromUri] int id, string email = "", string firstName = "", string surname = "", string orderByColumn = "", string orderBy = "asc", int start = -1, int end = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

the config -

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Default", 
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

the url with query params -

```
http://localhost:57597/api/OrganisationDetails/GetUsersInAnOrganisation/3?
orderby=asc&orderByColumn=surname&start=1&end=15
```

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi, I don't really want to use that url template, I want to have organisations/{id}/users as this style of uri (having a parameter in the middle of it) will be used throughout the api.